# Macbook pro bluetooth headset auto re-connect doesn't work. Requires pairing after restart

Tags: macos, bluetooth, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite, bluetooth-3.0

I have paired my Macbook Pro running Yosemite with Bose Soundlink OE bluetooth headset. Once after I restart the mac, I need to re-pair the bluetooth headset. Mac wouldn't save it in the list of the devices like it shows my bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

I have opened `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` and checked the list, the headphone is listed in the `DeviceCache`. The keyboard and mouse are listed under the `PairedDevices`. However the headset is listed in `DaemonNoRoleSwitchDeviceList` section. It wouldn't auto connect to the headset.

The headset tries to connect, the connected bluetooth icon appears on my mac for a fraction of second and goes off after which the headset's voice feedback replies - "Device not found"

Any idea what can be done to get it working so that the mac connects to my headset automatically after restart ?

Answer (score 1):

When I have had this problem, it was always because my headset was paired to another device, probably my iPhone. I needed to explicitly unconnect from the current device before I could connect it to the Mac.

Likewise, I need to disconnect it from the Mac before I can connect it to my phone.

Some bluetooth devices can be connected simultaneously to more than one device, I hear. I wish I had one of those.

Now, what *I want* is to teach my Mac *not* to connect to the headset automatically, but only when I ask it to connect. (I don't want to remove it from the list of paired devices, because I do sometimes connect it.)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but mine are the kind that can connect to multiple devices. It was some issue with my Mac OS which I couldn't figure out. I reinstalled The Mac OS X and it all seems fine so far.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a bit late but I had tried to troubleshoot Bluetooth on MacBook Pro which did not solve my problem.

It is so because this problem has nothing to do with Bluetooth at all. The solution to this for me is to **disable the setting found in *System Preferences > General* > Allow handoff between this mac and your iCloud services**.

If this doesn't solve your problem then please visit [this link](https://michaelkummer.com/tech/mac-bluetooth-issues/) to find other possible solutions.